# Loopback4 DefaultTransactionalRepository not working

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

Looking for help to implement transaction management in loopback4.
Using ms-sql database and loopback-connector-mssql as a connector.

i am extending repository with DefaultTransactionalRepository.

below is the code i am writing inside controller.

```
 1. const addressTransaction = await this.addressRepo.beginTransaction();
 2. const address = await this.addressRepo.create(addressObj); 
 3. addressTransaction.rollback()
```

Issue is, record which i created at line 2 is not getting reverted after line no 3, there is no error as well.
also i am getting addressTransaction object back at line no 1. above 3lines are just an example. moto is i want to revert back data that inserted at line no2.

If i execute below code into DB its working perfectly fine. record is getting roll back.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT into addresses(ADDRESS_CITY,ADDRESS_STATE) values('123','1234')
ROLLBACK
```

but some how connector is not working properly.

i checked with DBA, look like we are not setting implicit_transactions on with above transaction. does anyone know how to set implicit_transactions on.

Any issue with the way i am implementing the transaction? kindly help

Answer (score 2):

To group operations in a transaction you need to explicitely assign the operation to an transaction.

Here is the [official documentation of loopback4 transaction support](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Using-database-transactions.html#perform-operations-in-a-transaction):

> To perform create, retrieve, update, and delete operations in the
>   transaction, add the transaction object to the `Options` parameter of
>   the standard 
>   [`create()`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.defaultcrudrepository.create.html),
>   [`update()`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.defaultcrudrepository.update.html),
>   [`deleteAll()`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.defaultcrudrepository.deleteall.html)
>   (and so on) methods.

In your example you need to do something like this:

```
const addressTransaction = await this.addressRepo.beginTransaction();
const address = await this.addressRepo.create(addressObj, { transaction: addressTransaction}); 
addressTransaction.rollback()
```